# OpenCL C++ Wrapper, Buffer ErrorCode: -37

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm trying to create a class for OpenCL and get the Error: `clCreateBuffer`, with error code: `-37` and BuildLog Output: `71341624` (variing, has also been `69588024`) - I have `__CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS` defined.

I used this code:

```
template <class OpType, long length> void createBuffers(std::vector< OpType > arrays, OpType result, std::vector<size_t> size) {
        buffer[size.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size.size(); i++) {
        buffer[i] = cl::Buffer(contextCL, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_CO- PY_HOST_PTR, size[i], arrays[i]);//from here the exception seems to be thrown
        kernelCL.setArg(i, buffer[i]);
    }
    i++;
    result_buffer = cl::Buffer(contextCL, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, length*sizeof(OpType));
    kernelCL.setArg(i, result_buffer);
}
```

I'm testing this with 2 `float` arrays in `arrays` with `OpType` as `float*`.

Does any one know how to fix this error?
Thank you in advance,
- fodinabor

Comment: This error (`CL_INVALID_HOST_PTR`) only occurs if you pass `NULL` as the host pointer when using `CL_MEM_{COPY,USE}_HOST_PTR`. Can you verify that `arrays[i]` is always non-NULL (i.e. put a check/assertion inside your loop, just before the buffer is created)?

Comment: Thank you, I made: `std::vector<float*> arrays(3);` and then pushed back -> first 3 were `NULL`